# Type aware Map when using Iterator

Tags: functional-programming, rust

I have the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let xs = vec!["1i32".to_string(), "2".to_string(), "3".to_string()];
    let ys = do_some(xs);
    println!("{:?}", ys);
}

fn do_some(tokens: Vec<String>) -> Result<Vec<String>, bool> {
    tokens
        .into_iter()
        .map(|token: String| Ok(token))
        .map(|token: Result<String, bool>| token.map(|s| s + "a"))
        .fold(Ok(Vec::new()), |acc, s| acc.push(s))
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=00e583be8f9398f09dce309f8c5bc1dd)

After the line `.map(|token| Ok(token))`, I would expect that calling `map` would act on `Result` and not `Iterator` and thus be able to unwrap the `Result`, but I get `Result<String, bool>` as the output data:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `push` found for type `std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>, bool>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:12:44
   |
12 |         .fold(Ok(Vec::new()), |acc, s| acc.push(s))
   |                                            ^^^^
```

What is the best way of writing functional-like code in Rust?

I am aware of `and_then` but it seems to be unavailable to use in this chain.

Comment: What about [`filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map)?

Comment: @hellow I am not interested in skipping over the errors, I want `map` to execute only if `Result` is a `Ok` otherwise short-circuit the chain and immediately return the error.

This is how most functional languages handle such chains or pipes.

Comment: There's [`try_fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_fold) for that.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. For example, you reference `self`, `Token1`, `Error`, `some_init`, but we don't know what that is. If they aren't important, remove or replace them. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot really tell what you're exactly after, but - judging by the signature of `do_some` - I suppose that you have a `Vec<String>`, a function operating on `String`, returning a `Result<String, bool>`, and you want to apply this function to each element in the `Vec`, and get them into a `Vec` if all are `Ok`. If you encounter an `Err`, you want to return an `Err`. This can be acchieved as follows:

```
fn do_some(tokens: Vec<String>) -> Result<Vec<String>, bool> {
    tokens
        .into_iter()
        .map(|token: String| Ok(token)) // or any other Fn(String)->Result<String, bool>
        .map(|token: Result<String, bool>| token.map(|s| s + "a"))
        .collect()
}
```

This uses `collect`, relying on [`FromIter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html), and [you can convert an iterator over `Result`s into a `Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#impl-FromIterator%3CResult%3CA%2C%20E%3E%3E).

Note that you could make all this a bit more generic:

- The input does not need to be a `Vec`, it can be an `Iterator` over `String`s.
- We can parametrize it by the transformation function that converts a single `String` to a `Result<String, bool>`, or - to be more generic - to a `Result<String, ErrorType>` for some `ErrorType`.
- You do not necessarily need a `Vec` as the successfull return type, but anything implementing `FromIter` (which is - often - a container type).

A first step to do this may look as follows:

```
fn do_some<
    ErrorType,
    Tokens: std::iter::IntoIterator<Item=String>, // an iterable yielding String
    StringToResult: Fn(String) -> Result<String, ErrorType>,
>(
    tokens: Tokens,
    string_to_result: StringToResult,
) -> Result<Vec<String>, ErrorType> {
    tokens
        .into_iter()
        .map(|s| string_to_result(s).map(|s| s + "a"))
        .collect()
}
```

which can be used as follows:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{:?}",
        do_some(vec!["i1".to_string(), "i2".to_string(), "i3".to_string()], |s| {
            if s.starts_with("i") {
                Ok(s)
            } else {
                Err(s + " i does not start with i")
            }
        })
    );
    println!("{:?}",
        do_some(vec!["i1".to_string(), "i2".to_string(), "A3".to_string()], |s| {
            if s.starts_with("i") {
                Ok(s)
            } else {
                Err(s + " i does not start with i")
            }
        })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the results in an intermediate container, and then handle any errors from there (note that you will need to change the return value of your function):

```
fn internal_eval(&mut self, tokens: Vec<String>) -> Result<(), Error> {
    tokens
        // Use `into_iter` to iterate over owned objects
        .into_iter()
        .map(|token| parse_token(token))
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?
        .into_iter()
        .map(|token1| do_something_with_token1(token1))
        .fold(some_init, |acc, x| {
            // reduce
        });
    // ...
}
```

If you can't afford to create an intermediate container, you could also do this (slightly less readable):

```
fn internal_eval(&mut self, tokens: Vec<String>) -> Result<(), Error> {
    tokens
        .into_iter()
        .map(|token| parse_token(token))
        .map(|token1_res| token1_res.map(|token1| do_something_with_token1(token1) ))
        .try_fold(some_init, |acc, x| -> Result<SomeType, Error> {
            let val = x??;
            // ...
        });
    Ok(())
}
```

**Update**

```
fn do_some(tokens: Vec<String>) -> Result<Vec<String>, bool> {
    Ok(tokens
        .into_iter()
        .map(|token: String| Ok(token))
        .map(|token: Result<String, bool>| token.map(|s| s + "a"))
        .try_fold(Vec::new(), |mut acc, s| { acc.push(s?); Ok(acc) })?)
}
```

Comment: I have updated the original code example to be more clear.
Here is a rust playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=00e583be8f9398f09dce309f8c5bc1dd

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your playground code